# how to create a symbolic link from an ext partition to a FAT32 partition

Tags: windows-7, linux, filesystems, symbolic-link

On my Linux system, I want to create a symbolic link to a folder on my Windows 7 partition formatted FAT32. I use:

```
sudo ln -s /media/OS/Users/dennis/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft ~/.minecraft
```

However, I end up with a file in my home directory called .minecraft and when I try to access it, I receive:

```
bash: CD: .minecraft: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

is there a way to make the symbolic link to the FAT32 folder?

Comment: What says `df -k /media/OS/Users/dennis/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft ~/.minecraft` and `ls -ld /media/OS/Users/dennis/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft ~/.minecraft` ?

Comment: Don't sudo this. Just `rm ~/.minecraft` and then do the `ln -s ...` above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your home directory is not on FAT32 or similar, you should be able to create a symbolic link to any file located on any file system and even to non existing files actually. There is no need to be root as long as you are allowed to create a file, which should obviously be the case with your home directory. I suspect ~/.minecraft already was a bogus link.

Comment: I think that was the problem. I deleted the ~/.minecraft and then tried Turbo J's suggestion above and it worked fine.